# Python Tkinter scrollbox

Tags: python, grid, tkinter

I have the following code and keep getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'curselection'

I tried changing items to simple text messages instead of items from an array, but that didn't work. So I don't know how to fix this. I think that there's some kind of issue with using `grid()`, because the curselection and scrollbox code examples I looked at worked - unfortunately, they didn't use grid geometry manager. Any help is much appreciated.

```
#############################################################################
self.test = win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_NAME, None, 2)
self.array=[]
for self.printer in self.test:
      self.array.append(self.printer["pPrinterName"])

###############################################################################
self.box = Pmw.ScrolledListBox(self.Top,
listbox_selectmode='single',
items=(self.array[1], self.array[2], self.array[3], self.array[4], self.array[5],
             self.array[6],),
label_text='Select Printer',
labelpos='nw',
listbox_height=6,
hull_width = 200,
hull_height = 200,
selectioncommand=self.selectionCommand).grid(row=12, column=0, ipadx=30, ipady=30)
    Button(self.Top, text="ok", command=self.createini).grid( row = 14, column = 0, sticky = W+E+N+S )

def selectionCommand(self):
    sels=self.box.curselection()
    if len(sels) == 0:
        print 'no selection'
    else:
        print 'Selection:', sels[0]
```

If there's any other method to detect what user selected from scrollbar, then that would also be a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.box = Pmw.ScrolledListBox(...).grid(row=12, column=0, ipadx=30, ipady=30)
```

The grid method returns `None`, so `self.box` gets set to `None`. Therefore you get said error when trying to call `self.box.curselection`. You can fix this by moving the grid call like this:

```
self.box = Pmw.ScrolledListBox(...)
self.box.grid(...)
```